# How to sync video from iphone to mac without USB cable

Tags: iphone, itunes, photos, video

I am at my home. I made a video 30 minutes ago on my iphone 6s. when I go to my "photos" on mac, the video is still not there.

both my iphone and mac are connected to the same wifi network. same apple id and have plenty of storage in icloud drive.

Now how do I sync this video to mac immediately? usually every photo and video I take on my iphone becomes visible in my photos application on mac. but it takes its own sweet time.

I just want to know how can I make it happen immediately.

Let's say I want to do this without physically connecting my phone to my mac with a cable.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use **Airdrop** between your iPhone and Mac

Check out this article: http://www.macrumors.com/2014/10/29/how-to-share-files-mac-ios-airdrop/

You will need a Mac released in 2012 or later running Yosemite at the least. make sure you have wifi and bluetooth enabled.